# how to display content after onSubmit using form for a longer time than just a second

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form component that is made up of the search bar and a submit button. I want to display a calendar when the user submits a search and keep it displayed until a different search is submitted but it just displays it for a second and it goes away. How do I fix this?

```
function showDisplay() {
    setDisplay(true);
}

var result = "";
if (display) {
    result = <div>
            {filteredCalendars.map((calendar) => ( 
            <Calendar calendar={calendar}/>))}
        </div>
    
}

return(
    <div>
        <div className="text-center">
            <h1>Schedule Playlists</h1>
        </div>                        

        <Form onChange={() => showDisplay()}>
            <div className="search-box">
                <BsSearch/> <input type="text"  placeholder="Search calendar by store ID..." onChange = {e => setSearch(e.target.value)} required/>
                <Button type="submit">Submit form</Button>
            </div>
            
        </Form>

        <div>
            {result}
        </div>



    </div>
    
)
}
```

Comment: Try using `useState` for your result.

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work - used useState("") with result and setResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `onChange` on the `Form`? If you want to catch the submit event, I would normally handle `onSubmit`:

```
<Form onSubmit={e => {e.preventDefault(); showDisplay()}}>
    <div className="search-box">
        <BsSearch/>
        <input type="text"  placeholder="Search calendar by store ID..." onChange = {e => setSearch(e.target.value)} required/>
        <Button type="submit">Submit form</Button>
    </div>
            
 </Form>
```

Also, notice that the submit handler is calling `preventDefault()` so that it doesn't do the default submit action and refresh the page.

Comment: i didnt mean to use the onchange but the preventdefault helped thank you!